# In ReadyAPI, data created in excel from one POST request is unable to fetch from other POST request.

Tags: soapui

In ReadyAPI, I have a post method in a test step which will create one record of data with 7 columns. I have another POST request which has to use the data created from the first POST request. So, for this What I did is, I took a property from response of first POST request and kept it in a data sink. The datasink will generated he data in Excel. Now with the generated data, I have to POST the other request. The second POST request fails because the 2nd POST request is taking null as a request but the cell in excel is populated with data. any thoughts on this?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: have you tried using directly the output of your first POST request as an input for your second POST request ? ReadyAPI should allow that ...

Comment: @A.Joly Yes Joly, the first POST method will generate the data in excel and the second POST method has to use the same data. But due to some reasons the second POST method is unable to read the data created by the first one.

Comment: @A.Joly you said that "ReadyAPI should allow that". please let me know how it allows.

Comment: well, in your second request, besides your input parameter you shall click on the `...`. Then you browse your requests tree to get your previous POST request's output. Have you tried this ?

Comment: @A.Joly Hi Joly, instead of that, I used property transfer and passed the property as as inpput for second request. It is working now. I transferred the property across test steps. Now the issue is I cannot use property transfer across test cases. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I did use property transfer with the free version of SOAP UI but with Ready API you really should try. Then you would have someting looking like ${#[testSuiteName#otherTestCaseName#testStepName]#Response ...